# How do I get offset function working with max function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Many thanks for taking the time to read this.

I've got a function to return the closest value that is less than a given value:

```
=MAX(IF(O80:O85<Y80,O80:O85))
```

This works well and I now want to multiply it by the value on the right of the value that was found so I am trying to use the offset function:

```
=MAX(IF(O80:O85<Y80,O80:O85))*(1+OFFSET(MAX(IF(O80:O85<Y80,O80:O85)),0,1))
```

But this isn't working. I've done a similar thing with another function and the offset works perfectly Does anybody know why it's not the case here?
I am using Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Many thanks

Comment: Use `MATCH` to find which row number the maximum value is in, and `INDEX` to find the value in the same row of the other column.

Comment: Hello, are you sure the first line you write work ? The "IF" with a range don't mean anything special, is it a SUM ?
If you don't have #VALUE please be sure to refresh your worksheet or to be in Automatic Calculation Mode

Comment: Yeah the first line can't really work the way you describe it. The If part states: _any_ of the values in the range o80:o85 is below the value in y80 it will return the _whole_ range and not just those values that are below y80.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help

Comment: Why the `1+...`?

Comment: @Eddy, no the MAX will only consider those values less than Y80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset function first needs a reference, but the max function just gives a value.
This would be a solution based on your first function

```
=(MAX(if(O80:O85<Y80,O80:O85)),O80:O85,0))* (1+INDEX(P80:P85,MATCH(MAX(if(O80:O85<Y80,O80:O85)),O80:O85,0)))
```

**ARRAY Formula: CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this has worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the best pseudo-MAXIFS if you don't have Office 365 with the new [MAXIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883) is [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) as a standard non-array formula.

```
=aggregate(14, 7, O80:O85/(O80:O85<Y80), 1)
```

Multiply that result against the matching value in P80:P85.

```
=aggregate(14, 7, O80:O85/(O80:O85<Y80), 1)*index(P80:P85, match(aggregate(14, 7, O80:O85/(O80:O85<Y80), 1), O80:O85, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use INDEX-MATCH to make easily what you need:[image]
=INDEX(where-is-your-data,MATCH(what-is-the-target,where-is-your-data,Less-than-option))

In your case:

```
=INDEX(O80:O85,MATCH(Y80,O80:O85,1))
```

It's important to class your data in ascending order because the formula will give the closest value by checking your data one after one and stop without checking further the closest.

For the second part, if you need to multiply by an offset to the value on the right of the selected value, just make this:

```
=INDEX(O80:O85,MATCH(Y80,O80:O85,1))*OFFSET(INDEX(O80:O85,MATCH(Y80,O80:O85,1)),0,1)
```